# I am getting out of script error, why?

Tags: vba, excel

Here is the code

```
Sub logic() 
    'Declaring variables 
    Dim r As Long, i As Long, k As Long, l As Long  
    Dim num() As Long  
    Dim del() As Long  
    'Assigning Values
    r = 2  
    i = 0  
    k = 0  
    l = 0  

    ReDim num(0)  
    ReDim del(0)  
    Do Until Cells(r, 11).Value = ""  
        num(i) = Cells(r, 15).Value 

        'I m getting error over here
        del(l) = k - num(i)  
        k = num(i)  
        i = i + 1  
        ReDim Preserve num(i)  
        'Preserve the value
        r = r + 1  
        l = l + 1  

    Loop  

    r = 2  
    For l = 0 To UBound(num) - 1  
        Cells(r, 25).Value = del(l)  
        r = r + 1  
    Next l  

End Sub
```

Comment: Your chances of getting an answer would improve at lot if you described the error in detail. E.g., is it a compile-time or run-timer error? What is the exact error message?

Comment: It's a 'run time error 9' with 'Subscript out of range' error message

Comment: On what line??? Why force us to read your entire code? Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question (don't add more info in the comments)

Answer (score 1):

You are growing the `num` array but you forget to do the same with the `del` array. I believe you need to modify the code like this:

```
i = i + 1
ReDim Preserve num(i)
'Preserve the value
r = r + 1
l = l + 1
ReDim Preserve del(l) ' Add this line
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for your prompt reply but after adding this line I'm getting the same error message at 'num(i) = Cells(r, 15).Value' line

Comment: @Priyanshu Pandey  With Martin's amendment your code works for me; I have no failure with `num(i) = Cells(r, 15).Value`.  However, your code sets `Cells(2,25)` to `-Cells(2,15)` and, if N > 2, it sets `Cells(N,25)` to `Cells(N-1,15)-Cells(N,15)`.  Your code is a very complicated way of achieving this result.